# mongodb save in a nested object (node.js) application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I get "bookid not found" from my code.
I can add author and titles separately using postman but I can't seem to get the reviewsCreate function to to work, am I missing something? PLS help

my schema

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        author: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        rating: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 5
        },
        reviewText: { type: String, required: true },
        createdOn: {
            type: Date,
            "default": Date.now
        }
    });

    var titleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        favouredBy: {
            type:[String],
            required: false
        },
        reviews: [reviewSchema]

    });
    var bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        bookAuthor: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        titles: [titleSchema]
    });
    mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);
```

---

```
   router.post('/books/:bookid/titles/:titleid/reviews',ctrlReviews.reviewsCreate);
```

---

```
    module.exports.reviewsCreate = function(req, res) {
        if (req.params.bookid) {
            Bok
                .findById(req.params.titleid)
                .select('titles')
                .exec(
                    function(err, book) {
                        if (err) {
                            sendJSONresponse(res, 400, err);
                        } else {
                            doAddReview(req, res, book);
                        }
                    }
                );
        } else {
            sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
                "message": "Not found, bookid required"
            });
        }

    };

    var doAddReview = function(req, res, book, author) {
        if (!book) {
            sendJSONresponse(res, 404, "bookid not found");
        } else {
            book.reviews.push({
                author: author,
                rating: req.query.rating,
                reviewText: req.query.reviewText
            });
            book.save(function(err, book) {
                var thisReview;
                if (err) {
                    sendJSONresponse(res, 400, err);
                } else {
                    updateAverageRating(book._id);
                    thisReview = book.reviews[book.reviews.length - 1];
                    sendJSONresponse(res, 201, thisReview);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

this is what i get when i used your recommendation 
error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

when i put console.log(book); right under the doAddrivew function.

```
    { _id: 58dd21c3cb77090b930b6063,
      titles:
       [ { title: 'this is title',
           _id: 58dd3f2701cc081056135dae,
           reviews: [],
           favouredBy: [Object] },
         { title: 'this is the second tittle',
           _id: 58dd42a59f12f110d1756f08,
           reviews: [],
           favouredBy: [Object] } ] 
    }
```

Comment: Your book schema doesn't have a reviews property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your book schema have the `titles` property which further have the `reviews`

do

```
var doAddReview = function(req, res, book, author) {
    if (!book) {
        sendJSONresponse(res, 404, "bookid not found");
    } else {
       /* book.titles.reviews.push({  
            author: author,
            rating: req.query.rating,
            reviewText: req.query.reviewText
        }); */
        book.titles[0].reviews.push({ // to push in first element
            author: author,
            rating: req.query.rating,
            reviewText: req.query.reviewText
        });
        book.save(function(err, book) {
            var thisReview;
            if (err) {
                sendJSONresponse(res, 400, err);
            } else {
                updateAverageRating(book._id);
                // -----------------------------
                thisReview = book.reviews[book.reviews.length - 1];
               // thisReview = book.titles.reviews[book.titles.reviews.length - 1];
                // here also you may have to modify
                sendJSONresponse(res, 201, thisReview);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

▼ **UPDATE** ▼

---

1. First of All the `book` should be an instance of your `Book` Model.
2. The `titles` property defined inside `bookSchema` is an array, So when you want to add the data in `bookSchema`, `bookAuthor` property will have just a string, but the `titles` field would contain objects like `[{}, {}, {}]`, so you have to select the index of `titles` like `titles[0]` or `titles[1]` and then push onto which `title` you want to review

Note: as `reviews` of `[reviewSchema]` is also an array you have use index and select the required element from that array, to perform operations like update, delete like `book.titles[0].reviews[1]`

Suppose if i want to Push in `titles` array first element

```
book.titles[0].reviews.push({
    author: author,
    rating: req.query.rating,
    reviewText: req.query.reviewText
});
```

---

```
    { _id: 58dd21c3cb77090b930b6063,
      titles:
       [ { title: 'this is title',
           _id: 58dd3f2701cc081056135dae,
           reviews: [],
           favouredBy: [Object] },
         { title: 'this is the second tittle',
           _id: 58dd42a59f12f110d1756f08,
           reviews: [],
           favouredBy: [Object] } ] 
    }
```

Here as you have 2 objects inside the `titles` you have to select in which you want to push,

if you want to push the reviews in first object of `_id: 58dd3f2701cc081056135dae,` then select `titles[0]`

and for `_id: 58dd42a59f12f110d1756f08`, `titles[1]`

as your array will have multiple objects, so you have to match the object in which you want to perform the operation like `update`, so to filter the document you can make the use of `$` positional operator

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/position/

Please have a look at dot notation also
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation

Comment: i did that but i get this error
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

{ _id: 58dd21c3cb77090b930b6063,
  titles:
   [ { title: 'this is title',
       _id: 58dd3f2701cc081056135dae,
       reviews: [],
       favouredBy: [Object] },
     { title: 'this is the second tittle',
       _id: 58dd42a59f12f110d1756f08,
       reviews: [],
       favouredBy: [Object] } ] }

i wanted to push a review to the first title of the book.